# Word Chain (?) Bird to Nest

Tags: word, word-ladder

Lloyd is quite fond of math, and likes to incorporate math into almost everything he does. One weekend, the local newspaper printed a Word Chain puzzle, with starting point BIRD and ending with NEST. I had some trouble solving it, and asked Lloyd for help.  He told me that he had solved it, and handed me his copy of the puzzle.

When I looked at Lloyd’s “solution”, I didn’t see a chain of words, just a sequence of math operations. Seeing as this is Lloyd, I figured that it really *was* a solution, but I couldn’t figure out what he was doing.

Here is Lloyd’s solution. Can you reconstruct the actual word chain?

```
BIRD
     -  5408
     +    15
     + 17576
     +     1
     +    26
     +158184
     +  2704
NEST + 35152
```

Comment: Would this puzzle benefit from the [tag:word-ladder] tag too?

Comment: @Stiv - Yes. When I was typing tags, I got to "word", but it never proposed it, so I didn't know that it existed. Added.

Comment: Aha, yes it's not one of the top 5 most used beginning with 'word' so it won't have shown :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reconstruction:

> BIRD, BARD, BARS, CARS, CART, CAST, LAST, LEST, NEST

because

> Treat the numbers as increments (or decrements) in alphabetical range, from right to left. E.g. "AZ" + 1 = "BA". You can also think of the words as a number in base-26 with alphabetical digits.

this is evident because

> All numbers above 25 in the list are divisible without remainder by either 26, 26*26 or 26*26*26. Since you can only change one letter at a time within a word-ladder, this makes sense.

Comment: Are you really a robot?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that I did eventually come up with a solution of my own, and it turns out that it’s shorter than Lloyd’s solution:

> BIRD, BARD, CARD (instead of BARS, CARS), CART, CAST, LAST, LEST, NEST